# How to get all sub-documents with a certain value of a certain field?

Tags: mongodb

I have the following simplified collection: (consider all `street_names` are quoted)

```
{
    city_id: 1,
    city_name: "city1",
    streets: [
                {
                 street_id: 1,
                 street_name: street1 
                },
                {
                 street_id: 2,
                 street_name: street2 
                },
                {
                 street_id: 3,
                 street_name: street3 
                },
                {
                 street_id: 4,
                 street_name: street4
                },
                {
                 street_id: 5,
                 street_name: street5
                }
            ]
},
{
    city_id: 2,
    city_name: "city2",
    streets: [
                {
                 street_id: 1,
                 street_name: street1 
                },
                {
                 street_id: 2,
                 street_name: street2 
                },
                {
                 street_id: 3,
                 street_name: street3 
                },
                {
                 street_id: 4,
                 street_name: street4
                },
                {
                 street_id: 5,
                 street_name: street5
                },
                {
                 street_id: 6,
                 street_name: street6
                },
                {
                 street_id: 7,
                 street_name: street7
                }

            ]
}
```

Is there a way to query the collection in a way that will return only sub-documents that match a certain name `regexp`?
For example:
Get all sub-documents with `street_name` that contains "   " (3 spaces) in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure when using aggregation framework will look like:

1. $match documents - this step can be ommited as we need execute match again after unwind - but limiting working set is a good idea

> {$match:{"streets.street_name":"/REGEX_EXPRESSION_HERE/"}}

2. take out data from array

> {$unwind:"$streets"}

3. $match documents

> {$match:{"streets.street_name":"/REGEX_EXPRESSION_HERE/"}}

4. display only what is needed

> {$project: {_id:0, "street_id": "$streets.street_id", street_name":"$streets.street_name", city_id:1  }}

--before edit

You can use [regex](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) in [filter expression](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)

```
db.collection.find({"streets.street_name":"/REGEX_EXPRESSION_HERE/"})
```

Comment: i think this will return the documents that match the query.

Comment: what do you mean? - could you provide expected result?

Comment: sure, my expected result should be an array of streets from all cities which have a street_name that match the regexp

Comment: you can use aggregation framework - please see edited