# PyMongo - Searching Values of All Sub-Documents

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have the following entries in MongoDB about different drinks that I inserted through a Python script using the `insert.one()` command:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId('ffffffffffffffffff'),
    "Type" : "Juice"
    "Drinks" : {"Lemonade",
                "Apple Juice",
                "Orange Juice"
               }
 }
{
    "_id" : ObjectId('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'),
    "Type" : "Alcohol"
    "Drinks" : {"Rum",
                "Whiskey",
                "Vodka"
               }
 }
```

I want to input the string `Whiskey` in Python and I would like to extract just the type of drink:

`Alcohol`

How can I go about doing this? Has there been another similar question that was answered? I am having trouble with searching all values of "Drinks" in both entries and then returning just the "Type".

I found this related question:
[PyMongo- selecting sub-documents from collection by regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331182/pymongo-selecting-sub-documents-from-collection-by-regex) and also this: [How to get all sub-documents with a certain value of a certain field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35892825/how-to-get-all-sub-documents-with-a-certain-value-of-a-certain-field)
But I could not figure out how to apply those concepts to my problem/could not figure out how to write those out in Python.

Comment: This is not a valid BSON document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following query for this

```
db.collection.findOne({Drinks: 'Whiskey'}, {Type: 1})
```